Picaso library doesn't load images after first load
I'm loading the first image into PhotoOfBook. Then I try to load completely different images into PhotoOfBook2 and PhotoOfBook3, but the first image (which was loaded into PhotoOfBook) is loaded there. How can I fix this?
Picasso.get().load(selDeal.ImageFst).into(PhotoOfBook);
Picasso.get().load(selDeal.ImageScd).into(PhotoOfBook2);
Picasso.get().load(selDeal.ImageThd).into(PhotoOfBook3);

i dont know how it work
